# How can I prevent Thunderbird from displaying new mail notifications for messages that were moved from the inbox via a filter?

Tags: email, thunderbird, notifications

I have filters which move messages based on their subjects to different folders.  I don't need to know about these in real-time.  There are a small number of important messages that I do want to be alerted to (these stay in the inbox).

When I receive one of those important emails, the new mail alert displays the subjects of the emails that were filtered out, and not the one I just received (i.e the one in the inbox).

Instead of seeing an alert that says: "You have received 1256 new messages" followed by the subjects of 4 filtered messages (and not the important one that's in the inbox), I would like to see "You have received 1 new message" with the subject of the important one.

Note that I don't get new mail alerts when I get an email that's filtered, the alert shows these filtered emails *when* I get one that's not filtered.